# Django application structure,

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my Django project to Google AppEngine, however I can't figure out how to properly set up application entrypoint.

This is my whole project structure:

```
app.yaml
main.py
service:
    manage.py
    service-project:
        wsgi.py
        settings.py
        ...
    service-app-1:
        ...
    service-app-2:
        ...
```

How can I make it work? I tried to move main.py to service directory and use `entrypoint: gunicorn --chdir /service main:application` in app.yaml but it results in `Error: can't chdir to '/service'`, I guess AppEngine doesn't allow to change directory.

Comment: have you tried changing directory to `./service` instead of `/service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `entrypoint: gunicorn --chdir /service main:application` to `entrypoint: gunicorn --chdir ./service main:application` in your app.yaml.

The reason you are seeing `Error: can't chdir to '/service'` is because gunicorn is trying to change directory to the service folder in your root directory.

Adding dot in front of the slash will make it change directory to the service folder in your project, this is because the dot refers to the current directory where your app.yaml is.